# user uknown while using telnet mydomaine 25 in host considered as server sendmail

Tags: sendmail

I'm new in network administration, I choose to install and configure server sendmail on my host running with ubuntu 14. I created many users at this host considered as server and I tried to send email between those local users and it succeeded. I have one problem when I try to send email from this host to another host running ubuntu too and using the same domain I fail doing it

client1 has ipAdresse : 192.168.0.1 (server sendmail)

client2 has ipAdresse : 192.168.0.2

It gives me the error  : user uknown

```
           telnet 192.168.0.1 25
          Connected to mail.mydomaine.com.
          Escape character is '^]'.
          220 mail.mydomaine.com ESMTP

          HELO server
          250 ...
         MAIL FROM: <client1@mydomaine.com>
           250 ok
          RCPT TO: <client2@mydomaine.com> error  : user unknown
```

When I try to send email from this "the second" host to a user in my server sendmail I get a good result.

```
  telnet 192.168.0.1 25
          Connected to mail.mydomaine.com.
          Escape character is '^]'.
          220 mail.mydomaine.com ESMTP

          HELO server
          250 mail.myomaine.com
          MAIL FROM: <client2@mydomaine.com>
           250 ok
          RCPT TO: <client1@mydomaine.com> 
           250 ok
          Data 
          email from a remote host to a user created in server sendmail 

                     .
           250 ok 1231760818 qp 18364
               QUIT
         221 mail.mydomaine.com
         Connection closed by foreign host.
```

So can any one of you tell me why do sendmail can't know othder hosts using the same domaine? " mydomaine.com " why it gives me "unknow" ? please help fixing this.

Thank you for your help

Comment: This doesn't look like a good question for StackOverflow.  Try asking at serverfault.com.  It's geared more towards system admin questions (like this one).

Comment: @JacobRobbins SF is for professional sysadmins. "I'm new in network administration" indicates it's generally off-topic there.

Comment: please do any one of you have the solution of this error ?